# Android fragments refresh every time after returning back to them

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

This has to be really simple but I've never worked with fragments before and I'm lost here.

I searched and found tons of stuff on fragmets but I can't find an answer to my problem.

On my main activity I have a submenu with 5 buttons, basically a LinearLayout.

I have a List with 5 fragments in it.

When I press a button, I want to have one of the five fragments to be seen.

If I add the fragments with FragmentTransaction.replace(), the fragments are recreated every time. Everything refreshes and this is not what I want. Views are also refreshed if I return to a fragment by pressing the back button.

I couldn't figure out how "not to refresh" fragments. I tried using hide/show but I lose the track of the backstack at some point hence I couldn't iplement the back button behaviour.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you mean FragmentTransaction.replace(). Consider editing your question.

Anyway, the view will always be recreated when you change a fragment. It is your job to keep the information needed in a Bundle by implementing onSavedInstanceState() and then retrieving the info in onCreateView().

Comment: Thanks JDenais. But this is not good for me, it's a lot of work to handle recreation of fragment as there are 2 spinners in the fragment. When I recreate the fragment and set the spinners last selected items, onItemSelected of spinners fire and start doing some work. 

Also I save the information in static members as onSaveInstanceState() is not fired all the time a fragment is recreated.

I'll need booleans to handle the situation which is what I was trying to avoid, but there seems to be no other way.